# Vue.js and TailwindCss 3, safelist not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I dynamically set css classes in vue.js. These classes are listed in tailwind.config in the safelist. However, the classes are not generated in the output. So they are not available to me in the frontend. Apparently the docs don't make me any smarter.  Does anyone have the right tip for me?

```
<span :class="['border-4', 'border-solid', 'rounded-none', 'border-transparent', 'bg-transparent',  generateTeamClass(team.colorname)]">
```

tailwind.config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,vue}'],
  safelist: [
    'redbull-900',
    'mercedes-900',
    'astonmartin-900',
    'ferrari-900',
    'mclaren-900',
    'alpine-900',
    'williams-900',
    'haas-900',
    'alfaromeo-900',
    'alphatauri-900',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        f1: {
          50: '#f5f7fa',
          100: '#ebeef3',
          200: '#d2d9e5',
          300: '#aab8cf',
          400: '#7c92b4',
          500: '#5c749b',
          600: '#485d81',
          700: '#3b4b69',
          800: '#344058',
          900: '#283040',
          950: '#1f2432'
        },
        redbull: {
          900: '#3671C6',
        },
        mercedes: {
          900: '#6CD3BF',
        },
        astonmartin: {
          900: '#358C75',
        },
        ferrari: {
          900: '#F91536',
        },
        mclaren: {
          900: '#F58020',
        },
        alpine: {
          900: '#2293D1',
        },
        williams: {
          900: '#37BEDD',
        },
        haas: {
          900: '#B6BABD',
        },
        alfaromeo: {
          900: '#C92D4B',
        },
        alphatauri: {
          900: '#5E8FAA',
        }
      },
      safelist: [
        'redbull-900',
        'mercedes-900',
        'astonmartin-900',
        'ferrari-900',
        'mclaren-900',
        'alpine-900',
        'williams-900',
        'haas-900',
        'alfaromeo-900',
        'alphatauri-900',
      ],
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: The classes you listed in `safelist` do not seem to be match any classes that would be generated by Tailwind. For colors, they'd be a part of some utility class that uses a color, like `bg-red-500` or `text-green-500`, etc. Which utility classes were you hoping to generate `safelist`ed classes for?

Comment: Does that mean I would have to use bg-redbull-900 in the safelist?

Comment: It would mean you would have to use `bg-redbull-900` in the `safelist`.